# Line construction with double iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to build a line collection in order to follow the deformation of a spar at different time-steps. I manage to draw correctly the line for a single time-step with the following definition:

```
lstLines = [((xb, yb, zb), (xe, ye, ze)) for (xb, xe, yb, ye, zb, ze) in \
           zip(Spar_Res[i,:-1,0], Spar_Res[i,1:,0], Spar_Res[i,:-1,1], Spar_Res[i,1:,1],Spar_Res[i,:-1,2],Spar_Res[i,1:,2]) for i in range(Spar_Res.shape[0])]
```

Here the index b and e in (x,y,z) stand for begin and end of the segment, Spar_Res is a numpy array with the time on the 0-axis, the vertices of the spar on the 1-axis and the (x,y,z) coordinates on the 2-axis. I was hoping that adding an additionnal loop over the time, here the index i, will do the trick but I think I misplaced the loop or get it wrong in somehow.

Any idea on how to construct the line collection properly by iterating also along the time?

Comment: Could you give us some data to work with? Also, in a list comprehension you dont need to add the `\` if your doing something on a new line.

Comment: You do not need \ inside braces or parenthesis to continue the line.

Comment: `numpy` implies Python 2.x.  You probably want to use `itertools.izip()` instead of `zip()` and `xrange()` instead of `range()` unless your lines contain very few points.

Comment: Your list comprehension doesn't run, maybe you meant `[... for i in range(...) for (...) in zip(...)]`?

Comment: @drewk I put the \ so as the code might a bit more visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but I've written something close to what you have above in a clearer form using concatenate and reshape. I think if you think of your data in those terms your task will become much easier. Bellow T is the number of time points, V is the number of vertices.

```
# This takes your data and creates a new array that is (T, V-1, 2, 3)
lstLines = np.concatenate((Spar_Res[:, :-1, None, :],
                           Spar_Res[:,  1:, None, :]), axis=2)
# This reshapes the array to be (T * (V - 1), 2, 3)
lstLines = lstLines.reshape(-1, 2, 3)
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
lstLines = [((xb, yb, zb), (xe, ye, ze)) for i in range(Spar_Res.shape[0])
            for (xb, xe, yb, ye, zb, ze) in zip(Spar_Res[i,:-1,0], Spar_Res[i,1:,0],
                                                Spar_Res[i,:-1,1], Spar_Res[i,1:,1],
                                                Spar_Res[i,:-1,2], Spar_Res[i,1:,2]) 
           ]
lstLines = np.array(lstLines)
```

Comment: I am trying to plot in 3D the results I get on a cantilever to better highlight the deformation. I am trying to plot the cantilever by using segments to get a continuous colormap. To do so, I am building the line collection of the cantilever deformation over a period. I saw that to define a line in 3D you have to use a tuple list with the coordinate of the begin and end point. I am trying to build here that list. I manage the definition above but was ully aware of some dumbness.

I will try tomorrow morning at the lab. Thanks for the tip and the nice code you gave @BiRico

Comment: Thanks for the help. You rock!!! I will have to understand the simplified version a bit but it works perfectly!! You just save my week I think